# the connection between f.g. field extensions and varieties;

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, galois-theory

Is there a connection between finitely generated field extension and varieties .

Few days back, I asked this Question,

[image]

One person answered this question, but sadly he is no longer active on this site.I am attaching the image of his answer.[image]

Kindly mention some reference so that I can understand this connection between finitely generated field extension and varieties.

I would be thankful if someone can explain or give idea about this connection.

Comment: Any (good) introductory book on Algebraic Geometry presents this connection. E.g., see Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: @u1571372 What about Hartshorne's book ? Does he present this connection in his book ?

Comment: Extending the previous comments: One reference is Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*: Chapter 1, in 2.3, Example 11, page 30.